How to get rid of stuck unconfirmed transaction in infura.io polygon-mainnet chain?
The issue is that infura.io RPC node for the polygon-mainnet returns this transaction with getTransaction call, while this transaction is not seen on https://polygonscan.com/ or if other RPC node endpoint is used. In other words, infura.io sees the tx as pending, while it is actually not already.
The test.js file:
const { Web3 } = require("web3");
const util = require("util");

async function main() {
  const web3 = new Web3(
    new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
      `https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`
      // "https://polygon-rpc.com/"
    )
  );
  try {
    let tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(
      "0x490e87fefa3d8cfea96c5c48f38cff72adaa4b941abe1fbf2b6e112455f25a8b"
    );
    console.log(util.inspect(tx, { depth: null }));
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
  }
}

require("dotenv").config();
main();

package.json file:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "web3": "^4.11.0"
  }
}

.env file:
INFURA_API_KEY = "<API-Key>"

The node test.js call result:
{
  accessList: [],
  chainId: 137n,
  from: '0xec661f22d58b52401b0bffac217cca78e5c0b3d5',
  gas: 54473n,
  gasPrice: 68076466567n,
  hash: '0x490e87fefa3d8cfea96c5c48f38cff72adaa4b941abe1fbf2b6e112455f25a8b',
  input: '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000850b01e6967814f91fe215da8a47c29edd2142af00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029a2241af62c0000',
  maxFeePerGas: 68076466567n,
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: 12361823005n,
  nonce: 22n,
  r: '0xb5dedb32d824b1e8e82e257677b800c12ba1f60c2b4404093dd8343de018a10c',
  s: '0x7a1af57f4d733b3034c7d2768c58fb2f41e9d8b3c781414262e0d37ff8eeb520',
  to: '0x0397734093094ef7114ff232653370d568aa48dd',
  type: 2n,
  v: 1n,
  value: 0n,
  data: '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000850b01e6967814f91fe215da8a47c29edd2142af00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029a2241af62c0000'
}

If the "https://polygon-rpc.com/" is used instead, the result would be:
TransactionNotFound: Transaction not found
    at Web3Eth.<anonymous> (web3_test/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/web3_eth.js:663:23)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (web3_test/node_modules/web3-eth/lib/commonjs/web3_eth.js:44:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: undefined,
  receipt: undefined,
  code: 430
}

Which is an expected result, since this tx is old and was not included to block for a long time.
Looks like the infura.io RPC node cached this transaction, or just the getTransaction call for it and returns it regardless of the tx existence in the pending tx pool.
Is there a way to workaround this issue while still using the infura.io RPC node?
